# multiple select inserts

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to be able to have multiple select statements or values for my insert. The following works if I remove the second column name (notication_timestamp).

```
insert into notification (msg,notification_timestamp) select msg from data;
```

I want to be able to say:

```
insert into notification (msg,notification_timestamp) values (select msg from data,now());
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't put `notification_timestamp` on select query

```
insert into notification (msg,notification_timestamp) select msg,'value for notification_timestamp' from data;
```

So it may

```
insert into notification (msg,notification_timestamp) select msg,now() from data;
```

Comment: notification_timestamp is not in the query at all...separate data.

Comment: So if I wanted to add another random column and value to the insert that would be ok...just tack it onto the select even though it is unrelated to the query at all?

Comment: @user983223 Yes, as far as data type is the same

Answer (score 5):

Remove the values statement:

```
Insert into notification(msg, notification_timestamp)
    Select msg, now()
    from data
```